# Why the outputs are different?(how to make print(s1) to output Japanese)

Tags: python-3.x, python-unicode

I'm printing some strings which are Japanese's unicode,
why print(s1) is outputting Japanese's unicode directly, but not Japanese same with s2? How to make s1 to output "顧客"?
Thank you.

```
s_before = r'\(9867)\(5BA2)'
s1 = s_before.replace('(','').replace(')','').replace('\\','\\u')
print(s1)
s2 = '\u9867\u5BA2'
print('\u9867\u5BA2')
print(s2)
```

I expect the output is as below:

```
顧客
顧客
顧客
```

but the actual output is as below:

```
\u9867\u5BA2
顧客
顧客
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `\u` in `'\u9867\u5BA2'` is just a Python notation for a unicode character, not a literal `\` and `u`, so you can't just build a string of literal `\` and `u` and some codes and expect them to represent one unicode character.

You can instead encode the string into bytes and then decode it with the `unicode_escape` encoding to make it an actual unicode string:

```
s_before = r'\(9867)\(5BA2)'
s1 = s_before.replace('(','').replace(')','').replace('\\','\\u').encode().decode('unicode_escape')
print(s1)
```

This outputs:

```
顧客
```